# Nextjs Link not routing to page, if current url contains '#'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, anchor

I am on a page where the url contains '#' and a reference (localhost:3000/some-id#header)
On this page I have a link to a subpage eg. localhost:3000/some-id/subpage

The nextjs link to the subpage will clean the url and NOT navigate to the subpage. Clicking the link again will now work, because if the url doesn't contain '#' the link works as it should.

/some-id -> /some-id/subpage **works**

/some-id#header -> /some-id/subpage **doesn't work**

the link is a very normal link with only a couple of options (changing these options, didn't do anything)

```
<Link
  href={link} // /some-id/subpage
  scroll={false}
  shallow={true}
>
```

This is in a dynamic route eg. [page]/[subpage]. rendering works fine, it's only the link navigation in this case that fails.

EDIT:

Tried with legacyBehaviour: true and inserted an anchor tag myself. In this case the # reference was kept on the navigation.

so /some-id#header -> /some-id/subpage#header
which is not what i want. I just want to navigate to the subpage regardless of what url I am currently on.

EDIT 2:

Nextjs version 13.0

Found out something relevant. Had a custom onClick on the Next Link, which had no routing, nor did any e.preventDefault() - removing this fixes the issue. Had to remap the functionality from the onClick to a state listener in an useEffect. I will consider this a workaround, and not a direct fix. Maybe this is a bug.

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking. Are you trying to say that if there is ""#" in url, the navigation fails?

Comment: @itachi sorry but that is quite clear from the question.

Comment: @JonasPraem I think if you could share the version you are using?. As official docs says 
```Note: Before Next.js 12.2, it was required that the Link component wrapped an <a> tag, but this is not required in versions 12.2 and above.```